# Plot in GNU PLOT

Tags: gnuplot

I have to plot many lines in GNU PLOT.No problem with the X axis. The problem that I am facing is that most of the plotted lines are at yscale [0-0.05] ,few at range 60-70 and rest at 600-700. These numbers correspond to the y axis scale values. But after I plot I can see only 3 sets of lines all messed up. There is no clearity between the lines. Line at 0 and the line at 0.003 look like one single line. If I set yrange[0:0.05], the lines between this range are clearly vissible. But I want all the lines in the same graph. I have heard of breaking axis's and multi plotting..Can they be useful? how to implement them. Anyone pls help me.
Below  is the sript

```
set terminal png size 1300,1200 enhanced font 'Verdana,20
set output ' output .png’
set key  font 'Verdana,16'
set key bottom outside
set yrange[500:1000] 
set xtics("25k" 25000,"50k" 50000,"75k" 75000,"100k" 100000)
set grid
set title 'Performance Metrics'
set ylabel 'Metrices'
set xlabel 'FES'

plot ' input '  using 1:2 title ' A' with linespoints linewidth 4, 
' input ' using 1:3 title B'with linespoints linewidth 4,
'input ' using 1:4 title ' c' with linespoints linewidth 4, 
'input ' using 1:5 title 'D' with linespoints linewidth 4, 
 ' input ' using 1:6 title 'E' with linespoints linewidth 4,
' input ' using 1:7 title 'F' with linespoints linewidth 4,
' input ' using 1:8 title 'G' with linespoints linewidth 4,
' input '  using 1:9 title ' H ' with linespoints linewidth 4,
' input '  using 1:10 title ' I' Metric ' with linespoints linewidth 4


set output 
set terminal windows
```

input.dat is something like this:

```
25        0.002        0.05        899        455        444        0.08        0.00004        900        700        0.003
```

This way i have other rows. I have shown only the first one

Comment: Can you provide a sample of the data and the gnuplot script you have so far?

Comment: I have updated the problem discription above @choroba. Pls help

Comment: Do you absolutely want the y-axis to have a linear scale? Using a logscaled y-axis should make all your plots comparable, are you averse to this solution in any way?

Comment: @SidR Y athank u so much . I used "set logscale y". It worked for me :)

Answer (score 1):

I'll convert my comment to an answer then. ;)

Changing your y-axis from linear scale to logscale using,

```
set logscale y
```

should make your plots comparable.